# Why Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemSelection() returns null?

Tags: java

Is it a bug? I remember to have used this method successfully in the past. Is it possible that it happens only under Windows 7 64bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering this text in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getSystemSelection()), it's probably not supported properly on your platform;

> Some platforms do not support a system selection Clipboard. On those
>   platforms, this method will return null.